# React Native Maximum Call Stack Exceeded When Passing Parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting a strange error. I have the following bit of code.

```
<View style={styles.optionBarItem}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.optionBarItemWrapper} onPress={this.onIconPress("Events")} >
                          <Image source={imageMessages} style={{width: 20, height: 20}}/>
                          <Text style={[styles.optionBarItemText]}>MESSAGES(3)</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>



onIconPress( type = "" ){

    if(type == "Events"){
        this.setState({  iconOn: "Events"  });
    }
    else if(type == "Messages"){
        this.setState({  iconOn: "Messages"  });
    }
    else if(type == "Person"){
        this.setState({  iconOn: "Person"  });
    }
    else if(type == "Parcel"){
        this.setState({  iconOn: "Parcel"  });
    }

  }
```

If I run the above code the simulator stops and throws out a Maximum Call Stack exceeded error. 
[image]

However if I make the following change and don't include the parameter it runs fine.

```
onPress={this.onIconPress()
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `onIconPress` function in each render and passing the result to `onPress` prop. So in the render is called `onIconPress`, which sets state and triggers other render, which calls `onIconPress` again and so on... Therefore `Maximum Call Stack exceeded` error.

You need to pass a function here which will be called on press event. For example you can create inline arrow function which calls `onIconPress` with parameter:

```
onPress={() => this.onIconPress("Events")}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the explanation, that seems to have solved the issue.